# Array Index Out Of Range - Error when optional unbinding

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, option-type

I have an entity called `Settings` with an attribute called `backgroundColor` of type `Int`, if it is **1** then the view controller will have a background of white if **0** then a background of dark grey.

But I am getting the following error when trying to open the view controller;

> fatal error: Array Index out of range

For the following line in my function

```
    if settingsArray.count == 1 {
        setting = settingsArray[1]
    } else if settingsArray.count <= 0 {
      println("No settings in array")
    }
```

**View Controller**

```
var settingsArray: [Settings]! 
var setting: Settings!
var backgroundSetting: Bool = true

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    backgroundSettings()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    backgroundSettings()
}

// Function to fetch settings and change background
func backgroundSettings() {

    var error: NSError?
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Settings")
    self.settingsArray = moc?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as! [Settings]

    if settingsArray.count == 1 {
        setting = settingsArray[1]
    } else if settingsArray.count <= 0 {
      println("No settings in array")
    }

    if setting != nil {

        if setting.backgroundColor == 1 {
            backgroundSetting = true
        } else if setting.backgroundColor == 0{
            backgroundSetting = false
        }

    }


    if backgroundSetting == true {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    } else if backgroundSetting == false {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    }

}

//Button to change the color and settings
@IBAction func backgroundColor(sender: AnyObject) {


    if setting != nil {

        if setting.backgroundColor == 1 {
            setting.backgroundColor = 0
        } else {
            setting.backgroundColor = 1
        }

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)

    } else {

        println("No settings available")

        var settings = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Settings", inManagedObjectContext: moc!) as! Settings

        settings.backgroundColor = 1

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)

    }

    backgroundSettings()

}
```

Any ideas where I may be going wrong ?

Comment: I guess `settingsArray` is empty. Add a println of settingsArray?.count after the fetch to verify my guess.

Comment: I get a 0 followed by the fatal error: Array Index out of range.

Comment: So your `settingsArray` is empty. This explains the `Array Index out of range` fatal error. Your code is accessing an array slot that does not exist.

Comment: That is the reason for the optional binding :/ You are right that is where the problem is, when the array is 0 the app crashed with the error.

Comment: The optional binding will protect if settingsArray is nil. In this case settingsArray is empty, not nil.

Comment: A final note: when your sample code will compile successfully, I suggest that you post it to the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) community. Their reviews may help a lot, to make your code more synthetic and more expressive.

Comment: Oh thanks for that never knew about the Code Review community, also I have updated my code when checking the array but still get the error :/

Comment: Should be `if settingsArray.count == 1 {         setting = settingsArray[0] ...`. [0] not [1].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ETA:

I have been having another think about this. I have left my old answer below so that the previous comments make sense.

In `if let thisSetting = settingsArray?[0]` … if `settingsArray` is `nil` then the right side is potentially effectively `nil[0]`. Therefore I believe that this may eliminate the crash:

```
// ...
if !settingsArray.isEmpty {
    if let thisSetting = settingsArray?[0] {
        setting = thisSetting
    }
}
```

`settingsArray[0]` being `nil` would I think then be a separate issue. Which I think would relate to the lifecycle.

Previous answer follows:

I believe that the problem may be being caused by you calling `func backgroundSettings()` from `viewDidLoad()` - i.e. too early in the View Controller lifecycle - and before the values have been initialized.

Comment: I don't get the error when I comment out the function from viewWill and viewDidLoad. But the when the view loads it should set the background color whatever the setting is :/ that was the point.

Comment: What happens if you call it from `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: If you try calling that function from a test button does it work ok?

Comment: Yeah it works fine with a test button, I have commented out calling the function from the view will and did load and added a test button to call it. Also left the button action to change the color which works as well

Comment: I moved the function after the viewDidLoad and it worked until I reinstalled the app which set the array back to 0. So when the array in 0 the app is crashing, Therefore my optional binding is not working as expected.

Comment: @JKSDEV - I have edited my answer. I hope it might be useful.

Answer (score 5):

In Swift (as in Objective C and many other languages), the indexes of arrays start at 0. (See [this wikipedia article for a list on this.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28array%29#Array%5Fsystem%5Fcross-reference%5Flist)

This means when you check `if settingsArray.count == 1`, there will be only (exactly) one item in your list. Since indexes start at 0, this item will be at index 0, hence the Error.

So either you check if `settingsArray.count == 2` and leave `setting = settingsArray[1]`, or you change to `setting = settingsArray[0]`.

Comment: Oh yeah, *School boy error* therefore one of my fixes may of just worked. However i have accepted an answer.

Comment: So did the other answer fix your problem?  Damn, I had finally hoped for my first accepted answer...

Comment: At least, a vote. Thanks for recognising the truth, dear voter :)