# How to send HTTP GET requests on a time interval in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How do you continuously send HTTP GET requests on a time interval (every x/seconds)?

Currently I have a getMessages() function in my viewDidLoad() so that it will send a GET request on view load and populate a table view with the results from the server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369602/using-an-nstimer-in-swift

Comment: [send http request at intervals with swift3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43993602/6521116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `NSTimer` method `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`. You can say that it should repeat the timer and which method should get invoked if the time is over:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInSeconds, target: self, selector: "getMessages", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Since network requests can take unbounded time it would be better to fire off a new one each time a request succeeds or fails. How could I implement this?

Comment: Well you can do it inside the getMessages method.

Answer (score 0):

with swift3, use Timer, for more refer to this [**send http request at intervals**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43993602/6521116).

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(getMessage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```