# Just Upgraded To Xcode 8.3, now getting an error: "Type GameScene has no member: updateCounting"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

My code was running and functioning like it should, until I recently updated to Xcode 8.3. Now my code fails to run, leaving me with the error: "Type GameScene has no member: updateCounting". I have read similar questions and solutions, but none were able to help solve the issue. I am still learning swift, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    let highScoreDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    highScore = highScoreDefault.integer(forKey: "Highscore")
    highScoreLabel.text = "\(highScore)"

func scoreUpdate(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval){

    if (score > highScore) {
        highScore = score
        highScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "Highscore : %i", highScore) as String

        let highscoreDefault = UserDefaults.standard
        highscoreDefault.setValue(highScore, forKey: "Highscore")
        highscoreDefault.synchronize()

    }

    }

func updateCounting() {
        scoreLabel.text = String(self.score)
        finalScore.text = String(self.score)

        let highScoreDefault = UserDefaults.standard
        highScore = highScoreDefault.integer(forKey: " ")
        highScoreLabel.text = "\(highScore)"

    if (score > highScore) {
        highScore = score
        highScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: " %i", highScore) as String

        let highscoreDefault = UserDefaults.standard
        highscoreDefault.setValue(highScore, forKey: " ")
        highscoreDefault.synchronize()
    }

        self.score += 1
        print(score, terminator: " ")

    }

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.updateCounting), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

         // The above line of code is what's giving the error

        totalCoins = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Total Coins")
        totalCoinLabel.text = "\(totalCoins)"
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question but do not use `setValue(_:forKey:)` to save data to `UserDefaults`. Use `set(_:forKey:)`. And there is no need to call `synchronize`.

Comment: The class which your functions `scoreUpdate` and `updateCounting` are stored is called `GameScene`?

Comment: Why don't you call `updateCounting` directly instead of adding its class name `GameScene`?

Comment: Thank you for the tip @rmaddy!

Comment: @paper1111 Yes! that's where my functions are currently stored.

Comment: @Kegham K. I tried calling the function directly but for some strange reason I still get the same error message.

Comment: Why aren't you scheduling your `updateCounting` method from where you called it for the first time? Scheduling a method call from inside the method itself - doesn't seem right approach btw.

Comment: @P.Dane Please see my updated answer. Also as a suggestion for next time, please try to further simplify the code you show before posting. Narrow it down to the minimum amount of code necessary to show and explain the error you're getting. Also it helps if you link your project on github so that others can try testing it to see if they get the same error.

Comment: Were you able to solve your error? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

### Suggested Solution

Try adding @objc before your function name like this:

```
@objc func updateCounting() {
    // function code here
}
```

Then use `#selector(self.updateCounting)`

### Working Example

I took your code and heavily simplified it. I started off with a new Single View project. I added a GameScene.swift file and modified the ViewController class. See code below. Run the project and you'll see the log show:

```
Updating count: 0 
Updating count: 1 
Updating count: 2 
Updating count: 3
```

GameScene.swift

```
import Foundation

class GameScene {
    var timer: Timer = Timer()
    var counter: Int = 0        

    @objc func updateCounting(){
        print("Updating count: \(counter)")
        counter += 1
    }

    func updateTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounting), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let game = GameScene()
        game.updateTimer()
    }
}
```

**Github link:** https://github.com/starkindustries/TimerTestProject

### Syntax Options That Work

The following options tested successfully in this example project:

1. `selector: #selector(updateCounting)`
2. `selector: #selector(self.updateCounting)`
3. `selector: #selector(GameScene.updateCounting)`

Let's say you want to add a parameter to your updateCounting function. Change your updateCounting method name to `@objc func updateCounting(_ timer: Timer)` and change your selector to `selector: #selector(updateCounting(_:)`

### Syntax Discussion

As soon as I remove `@objc` the compiler shows this error:

> Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'updateCounting'
>   that is not exposed to Objective-C

One of the comments in another answer hinted at this too:

> I needed to add write the target function like this: @objc func
>   updateTime() {}
>   [Timer.scheduledTimer swift 3 pre iOS 10 compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695802/timer-scheduledtimer-swift-3-pre-ios-10-compatibility)

The Apple Documentation states:

> The selector should have the following signature: timer​Fire​Method:​
>   (including a colon to indicate that the method takes an argument). The
>   timer passes itself as the argument, thus the method would adopt the
>   following pattern:
>   - (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer

Even though I was in the Swift version of the documentation, it displayed that Objective C version of the timerFireMethod. So maybe the Timer class expects an Objective C selector just like the compiler error complained about. However, the documentation states that the method should have one parameter (timer), but I just tested it successfully using a function without parameters.

Comment: Using `selector: #selector(updateCounting)` resulted in an error saying: Argument of #selector cannot refer to local function updateCounting(). The 2nd suggestion resulted in same error message.

Comment: try adding @objc before your function name. see my updated answer. let me know. thanks

Comment: I was not able to solve the error just yet. When I type `#selector(insert function here)`, it's not able to find any of my functions including updateCounting. I believe the problem might be when I was recently organizing my code to look neater and putting related sections of code together. The error didn't appear right away. I thought the "timer" line of code might be in the wrong spot after rearranging it, so I tried moving it around to different locations but was unsuccessful. I don't know why GameScene is unable to locate any of my functions at the moment. The code that I organized:

Comment: was in the `override func didMove(to view: SKView) { ` function

Comment: I suggest you provide a link to your code on GitHub, so that others can see what else might be going on.