# Swift: prevent NSTimer starting automatically

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I am trying to use the `NSTimer` to increment the progress bar in my app when recording voice (see the screenshot)[image: App Screenshot]

```
let timedClock = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Counting:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    internal func Counting(timer: NSTimer!) {
            if timeCount == 0 {
                //self.timedClock = nil
                stopRecording(self) //performs segue to another view controller
            } else {
                timeCount--;
                self.timer.text = "\(timeCount)"
            }
            print("counting called!")
            progressBar.progress += 0.2
        }
```

The progress bar works only for the first time after I compile and run the project. When the recording is finished, the app performs segue to another view controller to play the recorded audio. However, when I go back to the view for recording, the timer/progress bar automatically runs. I suspect the `NSTimer` object is still alive on the NSRunLoop. So I was wondering how to prevent the `NSTimer` from automatically running.

Inspired by the answer in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369602/using-an-nstimer-in-swift), I tried the following, but the NSTimer still automatically runs.

```
let timedClock = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: "Counting:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timedClock, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because when your controller created it's properties are automatically initialized. According to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:) (and method's name) `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` create and return scheduled timer. So if you only want create your timer and call it by trigger function use it like this:

```
class MyClass {

  var timer: NSTimer?
  ...
  func enableTimer() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Counting:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }

  func disableTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the quick self-answer, as I just found out that I can use the `invalidate()` method to prevent the timer from automatically firing:

```
timedClock.invalidate()
```

Hope it helps someone in the future!

Comment: Remember to accept your answer once SO allows you to.